# Redirect as POST from one controller to another

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array in my controller, and I want to redirect to another route with this array data.

```
class HomeController {
   public function start() {
      $dirs = ['X', 'Y'];

      return redirect()->route('success', $dirs);
   }

   public function next($dirs) {
      dd($dirs); // aim is getting data here
   }
}
```

And my routes look like:

```
Route::post('/success', ['as' => 'success', 'uses' => 'HomeController@next']);
```

I tried get method but then I need to mess up the url and put a `/success/{dirs}` there, which I don't want.

What is the proper way of achieving this?

---

**Update:**

Using this doesn't work :S

```
public function start() {
    return redirect()->route('success', $dirs)->with('dirs', $dirs)->with('clientNames', $clientNames);
}

public function next() {
   dd(session('dirs') // returns null
}
```

Comment: If you just want it to use another controller, call that controller directly: `$this->next($dirs);`. Another alternative is to put it in a session while you redirect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `route` method's second argument is query parameters which will append your array values to the route like this `/success?X&Y`.

```php
function route($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)
{
    return app('url')->route($name, $parameters, $absolute);
}
```

Instead of passing your array to the route, use `with` method to put your data into the session and then retrieve it using `session` helper function on the other route.

Documentaion: [Redirecting with flashed session data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data)

Try this

**Route**

```php
Route::get('/success', 'HomeController@next')->name('success');
```

**Controller**

```php
class HomeController 
{
    public function start() 
    {
        $dirs = ['X', 'Y'];

        return redirect()->route('success')->with('dirs', $dirs);
    }

    public function next() 
    {
        $dirs = session('dirs');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... Although this would cause array to string conversion, it gave me the main idea. Cheers.

Comment: @senty Happy to help you :-)

Comment: I need to use `Route::get()` with your way, right? This will cause `/success?X&Y` :/ What is the way to keep it `/success` without parameters, after the redirect?

Comment: Yes, it works but as soon as I use `Route::get`, it puts `/success?X&Y`; isn't that the same behaviour for you? I wanted to achieve exactly what you did but without the parameters in the url, just `/success`

Comment: @senty No. `with` method doesn't append but rather store it inside the session which you can retrieve later in your other route. If you do this `redirect()->route('success', $dirs)` then it will append the values as query string because `route` method's second argument is query params.

Comment: Ye, that was the question initially. I'd be more than grateful if you can add this too in your answer

Comment: Thanks, but the aim is not passing data from controller to view, i want to pass data from one controller to another controller (route) so that the url changes, but url doesn't contain parameters

Comment: @senty No i just mentioned for a little detail on 'with' method. :-)

Comment: I think I bumped into another problem. I have added updated section in my question, can you please check?

Answer (score 1):

You should try with this:

Append you data `with()` method and access you data in another function with `session:get()` method like:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController {
    public function start(Request $request) {
        $dirs = ['X', 'Y'];

        return redirect()->route('success')->with('dirs', $dirs);
    }

    public function next(Request $request) {
      $dirs = array();
      if($request->session()->has('dirs')) {
        $dirs = $request->session()->get('dirs');
      }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, don't forget `Request $request` i guess?

Comment: I used `Session::get()` and `Session:has()` instead and worked like charm. thanks a lot